# Why is my iframe code for facebook not showing video description on mobile only?

Tags: wordpress, facebook, iframe

I am using iframe to embed a facebook video. I have changed show_text to "true" to include the description from facebook, and increased the height to around 600px to allow space for it. It works great on larger screens and even shows up when previewing in mobile responsive mode on my laptop, but the description and like/comment/share icons are missing when viewed on my phone. The video is still there but no information. Hoping someone has some ideas about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/#settings:

> `data-show-text`
> Set to true to include the text from the Facebook post associated with the video, if any. **Only available for desktop sites.**

So this isn't supposed to work on mobile.